# get_term_link not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I am trying to use the below code snippet to display an image and then wrap it in a link to a specific term archive page. In this case, I have a custom taxonomy (Series) with a few different terms. The variable $series outputs the Term Object, therefore I want to use the get_term_link function to get the URL to the terms archive page.

The documentation for get_term_link (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) says that I should simply be able to provide the term object and it will work, but it's not. I'm getting a partial-page load, meaning the code is breaking when it reaches this function.

Any help is appreciated!

```
$imageid = get_sub_field('series_banner', 'options');
$image = wp_get_attachment_image( $imageid, 'home-series-banner');
$series = get_sub_field('series_link', 'options'); //Returns the term object ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($series); ?>"><?php echo $image; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That field can return multiple term objects depending on how you've got it configured, so I'll guess that `$series` in this case is an array containing a single element, which contains your term object. Try inspecting the contents of series:

```
print_r( $series );
```

You'll probably see something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 1
            [name] => test
            [slug] => test
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 1
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

If this is the case, try passing `$series[0]` to `get_term_link`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out the plugin (Advanced Custom Fields) that I'm using to save and return the ID has a bug that is causing this. So my code above will work once that bug is fixed. I'll mark this as the answer though, as it's a good troubleshooting process for others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are getting term_id as a  string so convert it before function

```
get_term_link($series);

(int)$term_id=(int)str_replace(' ', '',$data[0]->term_id);
```